# Database Migration for Grafana

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, grafana

Currently i am running Grafana with sqlite3 db and trying to migrate the DB from Sqlite3 to MySql but while doing it on test instance, after migration not seeing old graphs.

Can someone please guide me if i can get the old/historic graphs also after migrating it from sqlite to mysql db.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions ..

Answer (score 0):

Grafana has no automatic migration tools from one database to another. You need export all your dashboards to json files in old Grafana, and import to a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

We used the migration script here with success: https://community.grafana.com/t/migrating-grafana-data-to-new-database/2454/2?u=thachnv92

(It did fail to properly import dashboards that had backticks in text panels, but worked on all the others.)